# Using SDK made for Android in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms, sdk

I'm currently developing a little project, i've bought a "smart lock" with works with Bluetooth and uses an open platform called TTLock. The resources are here: https://open.ttlock.com/doc/userGuide

The idea is to create my own App to control this "smart lock" using the methods created by TTLock.

The web page gives SDK resources for Android and IOS, but i want to program my App in Xamarin.Forms. My question is, can I "add" the Android SDK and the IOS SDK to my Xamarin.Forms solution and work with that methods, or i have to program first in Android Studio and later in an IOS IDE?

Thank you so much for your time and your responses. I'm learning about programming APPs on IDE, so all knowledge will be appreciated.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, can I "add" the Android SDK and the IOS SDK to my Xamarin.Forms solution and work with that methods,

The answer of the first question is **Yes**. You could refer to **[Binding a .JAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-a-jar)** document to use it in **Android**, and refer to **[Binding iOS Libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/)** document to use it in **iOS**.

> or i have to program first in Android Studio and later in an IOS IDE?

The second question is depends on you. You will not need to use native **IDE** to do that.

**For Android**, there are two ways to get the native library:

- Using Android Studio to download it
- Going to Source repository website to download it

**First** method, I think you already know that, from the document you will find the [sample steps](https://github.com/ttlock/Android_SDK_Demo#%E5%BC%95%E5%85%A5sdk):

[image]

The **Second** method, the shared document is chineses language. Therefore, you could find the source repository website here: https://maven.aliyun.com/mvn/search, and search by typing **tongtonglock** you will see the navtive libraries as follows. Then you can pick one to download.

[image]

**For iOS**, you could refer to its [sample link](https://github.com/ttlock/iOS_SDK_Demo) to get the framework.